# When i try to add results of average operation to an array, i get strange output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models, directors, movies, and ratings. These are their relations:
A **director** has_many **movies**, a **movie** belongs_to a **director**, a **movie** has_many **ratings** and a **rating** belongs_to a **movie**.

I'm currently trying to display a director's best-rated movie to display on a _director.html.erb patrial, so I tried this code:

```
<% array = [] %>
<% rat_val = 0 %>
  <% director.movies.each do |movie| %>
     <% if movie.ratings.count > 0 %>
        <% director.movies.each do |movie| %>
           <% rat_val = movie.ratings.average(:value).round(2) %>
           <% array << rat_val %>
        <% end %>
        <%= array %>
        <% break %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

to get the overall rating of a movie as a single value to an array, so I could then take the biggest value, then find a director's movie with the same rating and display its name and the rating itself, but with `<% array %>` the output is **[0.475e1, 0.438e1]**, which has the correct numbers, but somehow the decimal point is higher than it should be, the correct results are **4.75** and **4.38**. Also, I have no idea what e1 means, if anyone could enlighten me, I'd be grateful.

Comment: `.round(2)` returns a float which may be printed in "scientific notation". If you want a specific format, you can use a view helper like [`number_with_precision`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision) which returns a string (the examples in the docs omit the quotes for reasons unknown)

Comment: Thanks, that helped i used it like this: `number_with_precision(movie.ratings.average(:value), precision: 2).to_f`

Comment: `to_f` invalidates the whole formatting though :-)

Comment: You're right, my mistake :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.475e1` is `4.75`

Type it into your rails (or plain ruby) console and see.

The `e1` is part of [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) or e-notation. `0.123e2` stands for `12.3`

```
0.123 * 10**2
0.123 * 100
12.3
```

It's a display issue.